# Which statistical test to use to chose how to assign a subgroup to one of two other groups.

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, clustering

I'm trying to figure out the best statistical test to use in the following situation - I have a group of people, say group C who may belong to either group A or B, and I want to compare their similarity to group A or B over a series of variables and make a decision of which they should be grouped with.  At the moment I'm using a fairly simple analysis of comparing the percentage differences between both groups A and C and groups B and C over all variables and counting the number of times group C is closer to A over B to make the decision but I'm sure there would be a better way of doing this -- Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Suggest you look into 'discriminant analysis'. The famous historical example (due to Fisher) was the classification of iris flowers into varieties according to petal and sepal widths and lengths (4 variables). Fisher's original method was simplistic by today's standards, but it worked. Modern computation helps do more sophisticated versions.